# How can I upgrade OpenSSL version to openssl-1.0.1s in RHEL 5 machine?

Tags: rhel, openssl

My current openssl version is `openSSL 0.9.8e-fips-rhel5`. I want to upgrade this to  `openssl-1.0.1s`. The `yum update openssl` will not work here.

I removed openssl binaries from following path

```
/usr/lib/openssl and /usr/bin/openssl
```

And tried to compile it from source.

`./config --prefix=/usr/lib/openssl` but it throw following error.

```
*make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/openssl-1.0.1s/test'
Configured for linux-x86_64.
*** Because of configuration changes, you MUST do the following before
*** building:
        make depend
[root@test openssl-1.0.1s]# make depend
making depend in crypto...
make[1]: Entering directory `/root/openssl-1.0.1s/crypto'
../util/domd: line 25: gcc: command not found
make[1]: *** [local_depend] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/openssl-1.0.1s/crypto'
make: *** [depend] Error 1
[root@test openssl-1.0.1s]# make
making all in crypto...
make[1]: Entering directory `/root/openssl-1.0.1s/crypto'
gcc -I. -I.. -I../include  -DOPENSSL_THREADS -D_REENTRANT -DDSO_DLFCN -DHAVE_DLFCN_H -m64 -DL_ENDIAN -O3 -Wall -DOPENSSL_IA32_SSE2 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT5 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DMD5_ASM -DAES_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DBSAES_ASM -DWHIRLPOOL_ASM -DGHASH_ASM   -c -o cryptlib.o cryptlib.c
make[1]: gcc: Command not found
make[1]: *** [cryptlib.o] Error 127
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/openssl-1.0.1s/crypto'
make: *** [build_crypto] Error 1*
```

I want to upgrade this because of recently reported openssl vulnerability (Drawn attack). Please help me on this.

Comment: You shouldn't need to build from source, RedHat has issued [versions of `openssl` 0.9.8e that include the fix](https://rhn.redhat.com/errata/RHSA-2016-0304.html) for 5.6 and 5.9.

Answer (score 2):

Fixed error. Fixed by installing gcc.

Comment: looks like OP answer his own question, yet I agree a little more content would do no harm.

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty clear from this message what needs to be done:

> ../util/domd: line 25: gcc: command not found

You need to install the gcc compiler.

```
$ sudo yum install gcc
```

Comment: I had same issue. Thanks, this fixed it `yum install gcc`

Answer (score 2):

This/my answer does not explain how to update to *specific* version openssl-1.0.1s but it provides a different and more easy way **to update OpenSSL of RHEL 5 to the one of RHEL 6** (which is still supported, UPDATE: RHEL 6 is out of support since November 2020):

1. Install tuxad repo for RHEL 5: rpm -i http://www.tuxad.de/repo/5/tuxad.rpm
2. Update packages: yum update

More details can be found here:

[www.tuxad.de/blog/archives/2014/11/19/openssl_updatesenhancements_for_rhel__centos_5](http://www.tuxad.de/blog/archives/2014/11/19/openssl_updatesenhancements_for_rhel__centos_5/index.html)
[www.tuxad.de/blog/archives/2018/07/21/tuxad_rh5_repo_now_with_phpopenssl1](http://www.tuxad.de/blog/archives/2018/07/21/tuxad_rh5_repo_now_with_phpopenssl1/index.html)

This repo contains several packages which are rebuild against OpenSSL 1:

- httpd (also include other enhancements like ECDH support)
- postfix
- dovecot
- curl
- lynx
- mutt
- vsftpd
- w3m
- wget
- php
- php from RHEL 6 backported (in separate repo "tuxad-php")