# Clone a repo from github on RHEL 5

Tags: git, openssl, github

I am using RedHat 5.2 and I need to clone a repo from Github. Sadly, since February 1st of this year, they disabled TLSv1 and TLSv1.1

> Unfortunately, Red Hat 5 does not have a point release that supports TLSv1.2. We advise that users of Red Hat 5 upgrade to a newer version of the operating system.

[source here](https://githubengineering.com/crypto-removal-notice/)

I was able get the sources of `OpenSSL 1.0.2a 19 Mar 2015` and build it, then compile `curl-7.58.0` with the newer OpenSSL. I also compiled a newer git with the newer OpenSSL and curl

```
$ curl --version
curl 7.58.0 (i686-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.58.0 OpenSSL/1.0.2a zlib/1.2.3
Release-Date: 2018-01-24
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps pop3 pop3s rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: AsynchDNS IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP UnixSockets HTTPS-proxy
$git --version
git version 2.16.2
```

I am able to `curl` Github

```
# curl -Ivvv -k https://github.com
* Rebuilt URL to: https://github.com/
*   Trying 192.30.253.113...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to github.com (192.30.253.113) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
* ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1
* Server certificate:
*  subject: businessCategory=Private Organization; jurisdictionC=US; jurisdictionST=Delaware; serialNumber=5157550; street=88 Colin P Kelly, Jr Street; postalCode=94107; C=US; ST=California; L=San Francisco; O=GitHub, Inc.; CN=github.com
*  start date: Mar 10 00:00:00 2016 GMT
*  expire date: May 17 12:00:00 2018 GMT
*  issuer: C=US; O=DigiCert Inc; OU=www.digicert.com; CN=DigiCert SHA2 Extended Validation Server CA
*  SSL certificate verify result: unable to get local issuer certificate (20), continuing anyway.
```

But I'm unable to clone from it

```
$ env GIT_TRACE=2 git clone --verbose https://github.com/torvalds/linux.git
12:02:58.696627 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git 'clone' '--verbose' 'https://github.com/torvalds/linux.git'
Cloning into 'linux'...
12:02:58.697620 run-command.c:627       trace: run_command: 'git-remote-https' 'origin' 'https://github.com/torvalds/linux.git'
```

I also tried to init a new repo and set the Github link as origin but its not working either.

Am I missing a setting or a flag somewhere?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

On RHEL 5 I'm using git-1.8.2.3-1.el5 from Epel 5:

```
# rpm -qi git
Name        : git                          Relocations: (not relocatable)
Version     : 1.8.2.3                           Vendor: Fedora Project
Release     : 1.el5                         Build Date: Di 26 Apr 2016 19:30:16 CEST
```

It seems to require OpenSSL 1:

```
# ldd /usr/bin/git-remote-https
    libssl.so.10 => /lib/libssl.so.10 (0x00b2a000)
    libcrypto.so.10 => /lib/libcrypto.so.10 (0x00595000)
```

On my system it is resolved by this:

```
# rpm -qf /lib/libssl.so.10
openssl1-1.0.1e-57.el5_11
```

And this one is coming from "tuxad repo": 
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/459187/284960

I have no issues on cloning from github.